# How to add a toggle function to an AutoHotkey script?

Tags: autohotkey

I have an AutoHotKey script, and I would like to add some conditional behavior to the script.  For instance, in the script below, send **"8"** instead of "7" if the user is holding down mouse 2 at the time the key is sent:

```
f::
Send {p down}  
Sleep 200  
Send {p up}
sleep, 899
Send, 7
return

2::
Send {o down}  
Sleep 200  
Send {o up}
Send, 7
sleep, 899
Send, 7
return

capslock::suspend
return
```

How can I toggle the behavior of the script so that it does something different based on the state of the mouse at the time that line of the script is executed?  is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
f::
    If GetKeyState( "RButton", "P" )
        var = 8
    else
        var = 7
    Send {p down}
    Sleep 200
    Send {p up}
    sleep, 899
    Send, %var%
return

2::
    If GetKeyState( "RButton", "P" )
        var = 8
    else
        var = 7
    Send {o down}
    Sleep 200
    Send {o up}
    Send, %var%
    sleep, 899
    Send, %var%
return

capslock::
    suspend
return
```

Comment: and how to add to the script that releasing the mause2 key returned to the value "7"

Comment: I've updated the code, now the check for rbutton held or not is inside the commands.